# Bind images to listbox with datatemplate from app package folder

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Hi I need bind images to listbox but when I try it I get FILE NOT FOUND but file is stored in application package in folder layoutGraphics. I try put files to default folder but I get same result anyone know what is bad?

```
var file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("ms-appx:///layoutGraphics/offline.png");
        var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
        var img = new BitmapImage();
        img.SetSource(fileStream);
        ImgSource = img;
```

// property

```
private BitmapImage _imgSource;
    public BitmapImage ImgSource
    {
        get { return _imgSource; }
        set
        {
            _imgSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyDatasMessagesUserList");
        }
    }
```

Or anyone know better solution how I can bind imagess from app folder to my listbox with datatemplate?

Comment: @"/layoutGraphics/offline.png" or use resources

Comment: @ not working - file not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder is retriving file from the application storage not the package. For the package folder you need to use Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation. Also the GetFileAsync take just the name of a file not a full path. 
Here is the code to acomplish what you want:

```
var layoutGraphiceFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("layoutGraphics")
var file=await layoutGraphiceFolder.GetFileAsync("offline.png");
```

Another way to do it with the full path is:

```
var file=await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///layoutGraphics/offline.png"));
```

Comment: second idea is working but now I get:Error: BindingExpression path error: 'ImgSource' property not found on 'Un.BindingData'. BindingExpression: Path='ImgSource' DataItem='Un.BindingData'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image' (Name='imgMessengerIsOffline'); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')

Comment: Is ImgSource a property of the class BindingData because this error mean that the DataContext of the Image is an object of type BindingData?

Comment: Also I think there is an error on: OnPropertyChanged("MyDatasMessagesUserList"); , should probably be OnPropertyChanged("ImgSource");